# Specify a relative path where an absolute is required in batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, relative-path, absolute-path

I have the following batch file:

```
"C:\TapTest\PsExec.exe" /accepteula -i -s "C:\TapTest\tapinstall.exe" 
    ->  install "C:\TapTest\driver\OemWin2k.inf" tap0901
```

The location of the batch file is:

```
c:\TapTest\TapInstall.bat
```

I want to be able to do the following (using relative paths):

```
"PsExec.exe" /accepteula -i -s "tapinstall.exe" install "driver\OemWin2k.inf" tap0901
```

But the  tapinstall.exe requires an absolute path as an argument. How can I get the batch file to give the absolute path without hardcoding it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
"PsExec.exe" /accepteula -i -s "%~dp0tapinstall.exe" install "%~dp0driver\OemWin2k.inf" tap0901
```

`%0` = reference to the current batch file

`%~dp0` = drive and path where the batch file is located

---

Comment: Sweet thanks. I edited your answer to add `%~dp0` to the `tapinstall.exe` too. It's awaiting review.

Comment: @MC ND : how to achieve it in PowerShell..??

Comment: @Koder101 `$ScriptDirectory = Split-Path $script:MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path`